# mongodb aggregate on array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to group my participants array in to such a way that for a single participant I should get all the meeting under that participant in an array.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5fc73e7131e6a20f6c492178",
        "participants": [
            {
                "_id": "5fc74bc5e7c54d0ea8f133ca",
                "rsvp": "Yes",
                "name": "Participant 1",
                "email": "participant1@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fc74e1254b8d337b4ae36d2",
                "rsvp": "Not Answered",
                "name": "Participant 2",
                "email": "participant2@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Meeting 1",
        "startTime": "2020-11-01T18:30:00.000Z",
        "endTime": "2020-11-03T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5fc73f1cdfc45d3ca0c84654",
        "participants": [
            {
                "_id": "5fc74bc5e7c54d0ea8f133ca",
                "rsvp": "Yes",
                "name": "Participant 2",
                "email": "participant2@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "title": "Meeting 2",
        "startTime": "2020-11-01T18:30:00.000Z",
        "endTime": "2020-11-03T18:30:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

my expected result should be like

```
[{
"participant": {
                "_id": "5fc74bc5e7c54d0ea8f133ca",
                "rsvp": "Yes",
                "name": "Participant 1",
                "email": "participant1@gmail.com"
},
meetings: [{meeting1, meeting2, ...and so on}]
},
{
"participant": {
                "_id": "5fc74bc5e7c54d0ea8f133ca",
                "rsvp": "Yes",
                "name": "Participant 2",
                "email": "participant2@gmail.com"
},
meetings: [{meeting2, meeting3, ...and so on}]
}
]
```

I'm kinda stuck for hours to figure it out. I tried the approach by using $group and $unwind but I was getting participants as an array consisting of a single participant(object). and on that I was unable to run $match to match according to the participant's email  because participants field was an array.
I tried this

```
            const docs = await Meeting.aggregate([
                { $unwind: '$participants' },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'participants',
                        localField: 'participants',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'participants'
                    }
                },
                { $match },
                { $group: { _id: "$participants", meetings: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
            ]);
```

but this is not matching the expected result which I want it to be.

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Comment: Yes. thank you so much.

Comment: Could you provide me some links from I could practice or learn aggregate ? cause everytime I look at the mongodb docs I get lost.

Comment: Mongodb documentation is perfect. Please go through it first. If you need additional, use https://university.mongodb.com/ . Then please try to answer the question in stakoverflow which helps you a lot to improve knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unwind to deconstruct the array and use group to get your desired output

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$participants"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$participants._id",
      participants: {
        $first: "$participants"
      },
      meetings: {
        "$addToSet": "$title"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working  [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uI-x0oTbYye)**